# share button for own site Django

Tags: python, django

I want to implement a ''share on my profile'' button on my page but I have a hard time how to do so. When I try to find something like that (google/here) the results are "how to share something from your site on twitter/facebook". If there is a similar question please share the link I was not able to find something.

So i have a site where users have a profile where the liked content is displayed and I would like to give the user the option to share a Post on his own profile with a personal comment(like FB/twitter does).

My problem is that I don't know how to implement this into my models. If I want to save the "shared" post in a QuerySet in the UserProfile model I don't know where to save the comment for each shared post. If I make an extra table for all the shared posts with a extra form combined its a total mess since each post is saved individually and I don't know how to combine the existing image in to the form where the user writes his comment .

Can anybody tell me in which direction I have to walk? Feeling a bit lost on this one.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to make an extra table, django will do it for you, if you'll use ManyToManyField in your Post model.
See this docs https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/fields/#manytomanyfield